# Python - ELIF statements do not continue WHILE loop

Tags: python

In class we are starting with a base program and are going to continue to build upon it. I am stuck and not sure why when the program reaches a ELIF statement it doesnt return to the beginning of the WHILE loop like it does for the first IF statement

```
print("Great Scott! Marty we need to go back to the future!")
print("Marty, lets do a checklist!")
engine = None
circuit = None

while (engine !=1 and circuit != 1):
    engine = int(input("Engine on or off? Enter 1 for ON or 0 for OFF\n"))
    circuit = int(input("Circuit on or off? Enter 1 for ON or 0 for OFF\n"))

    if (engine == 0 and circuit == 0):
         print("Marty! we have to turn everything on before we can time travel!")
         print("Lets check again!")

    elif (engine == 1 and circuit == 0):
        print("Lets turn on the time cicruit")
        print("Lets check again!")

    elif (engine == 0 and circuit == 1):
        print("Turn on the engine!")
        print("Lets check again!")

    else:
        print("Great! lets start driving")
        speed = 0
        while speed < 88:
            speed = int(input("Whats our current speed?\n"))

            if speed < 88:
                print("We need to go faster!")

            else:
                print("Flux Capacitor Fully Charged")
                print("Marty, where we're going, we dont need roads!")
```

Comment: Take a close look at your `while` condition. Are *both* conditions true when `engine == 1` is true? Are they both true when `circuit == 1` is true?

Answer (score 1):

Actually just change *and* to *or*

```
while (engine !=1 or circuit != 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be restarting variables `engine` and `circuit` to 0. Your loop requires the variables to be different to 1 in order to keep running.

Try it now:

```
print("Great Scott! Marty we need to go back to the future!")
print("Marty, lets do a checklist!")
engine = None
circuit = None

    while (engine !=1 and circuit != 1):
        engine = int(input("Engine on or off? Enter 1 for ON or 0 for OFF\n"))
        circuit = int(input("Circuit on or off? Enter 1 for ON or 0 for OFF\n"))

        if (engine == 0 and circuit == 0):
             print("Marty! we have to turn everything on before we can time travel!")
             print("Lets check again!")

        elif (engine == 1 and circuit == 0):
            print("Lets turn on the time cicruit")
            print("Lets check again!")
            engine = 0
            circuit = 0

        elif (engine == 0 and circuit == 1):
            print("Turn on the engine!")
            print("Lets check again!")
            engine = 0
            circuit = 0
        else:
            print("Great! lets start driving")
            speed = 0
            while speed < 88:
                speed = int(input("Whats our current speed?\n"))

                if speed < 88:
                    print("We need to go faster!")

                else:
                    print("Flux Capacitor Fully Charged")
                    print("Marty, where we're going, we dont need roads!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (engine !=1 and circuit != 1):
```

The above statement means both engine and circuit should not be equal to 1. If either one of them is 1, then condition evaluates to `False` and loop ends.

Now, in your `elif` cases, either engine or circuit is 1, due to which the loop condition evaluates to `False` and loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (engine !=1 and circuit != 1):
```

Should be changed to:

```
while (engine !=1 or circuit != 1):
```

In the first case(the one with `and`) will continue the loop only if both the engine and circuit aren't equal to 1.(some pseudocode: `do something while condition 1 is true AND while condition 2 is true` whereas with `or` it will be `do something while condition 1 is true OR if condition 2 is true` ).